# Dot grid in latex as background

Tags: grids

I'm trying to make a printable daily planner using Tex. This would be my first project.
What I want to achieve is for all the pages to have a dot grid background with the standard 0.5 cm space between dots and the ability to vary opacity and color. I want to be able to put pictures, tables and text on top of it. When I do get something that resembles a dot grid using tikz or https://github.com/jrblevin/dot-grid-paper I cant seem to get the text to be on top of the grid.
Is there a way to do this? A similar example or package recommendation would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried? You may just need to add `remember picture, overlay` as options to the `tikzpicture` environment, but it is hard to guess without seeing code.  We don't know what you're using to make the grid, for example. If you're using something more like `picture`, you might look at the `page` packages (`everypage`, `afterpage`, `background`, `esopic`, `wallpaper` and so on).